# setValue(contLength) is returning unexpected value

Tags: http-headers, google-apps-script, urlfetch

Here is the complete script.

```
function check() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet1 = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var dataRange = sheet1.getDataRange().getValues();
      for (var i = 1; i < dataRange.length; i++) {
        var stringToDisplay=dataRange[i][0];
        var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(stringToDisplay);
        var date=result.getHeaders()['Date'];
        var contType=result.getHeaders()['Content-Type'];
        var contLength=result.getHeaders()['Content-Length'];
        for(j=0;j<10;j++)
        {
          if(contLength=="undefined")
          {
            var contLength=result.getHeaders()['Content-Length'];
          }
        }
        var server=result.getHeaders()['Server'];
        var exp=result.getHeaders()['Expires'];
        var resp=result.getResponseCode();
        var myDate=new Date();    
        sheet1.getRange(i+1,2).setValue(date);
        sheet1.getRange(i+1,3).setValue(contLength);
        sheet1.getRange(i+1,4).setValue(contType);
        sheet1.getRange(i+1,5).setValue(server);
        sheet1.getRange(i+1,6).setValue(exp);
        sheet1.getRange(i+1,7).setValue(resp);
        sheet1.getRange(i+1,8).setValue(myDate.toString());
      }
}
```

I am expecting a int value here - sheet1.getRange(i+1,3).setValue(contLength). Instead it is bringing either undefined or int value, every-time the script is executed.

What could be the issue here?

Thanks,
Samir

Comment: Your script is not really 'testable' as it is, could you provide a link to the spreadsheet in which it is running?

Comment: @Sergeinsas Here is the link to spreadsheet - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Ag_5RR32Q1yAdHVPWXBEUTNkT19hQ2wwOURGb0pTc3c

Answer (score 0):

While trying to debug your issue, I've added the Utilities.Sleep(1000) function to give it some time, but it gets stuck at 5 out of 17 having 'undefined'. All have "text/html; charset=utf-8" as Content-Type. It could be that only the Apache-Servers deliver the correct format (as they result in an integer). You should look at that next, to see if it's the issue.

See my [shared doc](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JsevmqZHGluinvBdyI6R8uXInMolTpPHOsLNNXUrZKY/edit).